# Issues with using npm packages in Google Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, terraform

I am currently working on deploying a Google Cloud Function and associated resources (bucket, archive, etc) using Terraform. Running my `terraform` commands from Git Bash on Windows 10 I have a good amount of Terraform and AWS experience, but GCP is new to me. I've written many AWS Lambdas using TFE, but it has been about 2.5 years since.

The GC Function is using Node.js and `express`, however I am having problems accessing `express` in my deployed function. I actually want to use TypeScript but after running into some issues I decided to create a simple bare bones function with just javascript. Once I figure this out I'll move to update it to TypeScript.

**Project Structure:**

```
.
├── terraform
│   ├── modules
│   │   └── function
│   │       ├── main.tf
│   │       ├── outputs.tf
│   │       └── variables.tf
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── backend.tf
│   ├── outputs.tf
│   └── variables.tf
└── src
|     └── index.js
└── package.json
└── node_modules
```

**Relevant Terraform:**

```
data "archive_file" "source" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_dir  = "../src" # Here is the potential issue
  output_path = "/tmp/function-${local.timestamp}.zip"
}
```

**Issues**

When executing `terraform apply` in the root `terraform` directory, I get the following:

> Error: Error waiting for Creating CloudFunctions Function: Error code 3, message: Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code.

And within the GCP Logs Explorer:

> Provided module can't be loaded.

> Did you list all required modules in the package.json ?

> "Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'express'"

**Resolution Efforts**

You can see above in my `archive_file` `source_dir` that I am pointing to the `src` folder containing my `index.js`.

After doing some digging, I've realized that because the `package.json` containing my `express` dependency is not in that `src` directory, but instead at *project root*, it does not get included in my zipped folder.

However, if I set the `archive_file` `source_dir` to the project root, `terraform apply` tries to read the produced `terraform.tfstate` file within the root `terraform` directory, and it gives me this error:

> Error: error archiving directory: error reading file for archival: read C:\Users<user><proj>\test-project\terraform\terraform.tfstate: The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file.

**Questions**

1. How can I include npm dependencies that are in my `package.json` in my zipped GCP function folder?
2. Do I have to include `node_modules` directly in the archive file? Or will the GC Function automatically recognize the package.json in the zipped dir, and install my dependencies?
3. Would using a GCP backend vs local backend resolve the .tfstate issue?

I'd greatly appreciate some help, and hope I provided good enough information! Thank you all!

Comment: I have found a similar question with no full resolution here, although it is NOT using Terraformbut deploying using gcp command line, which I am not using for deployment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57969899/failed-to-loading-node-modules-in-google-cloud-function-index-js-not-on-the-pr?rq=1

Comment: Did you try to deploy your functions only? Without terraform to be sure that it works unitarily?

Comment: If there is no reason your Terraform and function code need to share the same root directory I would split them into separate subdirectories. You could then zip up your function code without touching the state file.

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to update my `archive_file` to:

```
data "archive_file" "source" {
  type        = "zip"
  output_path = "/tmp/function-${local.timestamp}.zip"
  source_dir  = "../../../build/src"
}
```

I also had to move my `package.json` to the `build/src` folder as well so the dependencies could be recognized.

Isn't ideal since if I do an `npm i <package>` I need to also copy it into the `build/package.json`, but it works now as the Function recognizes the `build/package.json` and installs the right dependencies.

I will probably add a script on build to copy the root `package.json` to the `build` folder as well.